# How do I change a variable in a child element that has ng-click in the parent element.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Consider this code:

```
    <section class="page-section about-us" scroll-bookmark="about-us" ng-click="activeSection=true" ng-init="activeSection=false">
    <div class="page-content sub-content active-section">{{activeSection}}
        <div class="page-border">
            <a href="#" class="close-section"><img src="public/images/go-back-icon.png" />
                <div class="back-button" ng-click="activeSection=false">CLOSE</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

I have an ng-click in the  that element which changes the value of 'activeSection' to true. Inside of it, I have another button that can switch this back to it's initial value (false).

In the actual app, it would show or hide this child button based on a class added to the  element,just to give you a little background what I'm trying to achieve.

When I click on the  element, it does as I expect it to be: switch the value to 'true'. But when I click on the .back-button element with the other ng-click, it fails to register the changed value.

Why is that?

They're both inside the same controller, btw. If there's a solution that doesn't involve creating a new controller, it would be better.

Comment: So you have a button with `ng-click` that sets the variable to false BUT its parent also has a `ng-click` which does the opposite. Is that what you tried to do?

Comment: Probably both actions are performed BUT the `ng-click` of `section` is executed after, so the variable remains as `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on your back button, `activeSection` will be **false** but then your event will be **propagated** to its parent so the `ng-click` of `Section` will be executed too and `activeSection` will be true again.

In order to make your code work, you should **stop the propagation** of the ng-click event after changing the value of your variable in your `back-button`.

Your code would look like this:

```
<section class="page-section about-us" scroll-bookmark="about-us" ng-click="activeSection=true" ng-init="activeSection=false">
<div class="page-content sub-content active-section">{{activeSection}}
      <div class="page-border">
          <a href="#" class="close-section"><img src="public/images/go-back-icon.png" />
              <div class="back-button" ng-click="activeSection=false; $event.stopPropagation();">CLOSE</div>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I so wanted this to work, but unfortunately, it cannot (or I'm just dumb). Do you have a working demo of this?

Comment: OMG. This actually worked. I take it back! LOL. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that you are putting the close button inside the element which have already `ng-click`, that's why when you are clicking the close button, it executes the parent `ng-click` and stop propagation for all other click events happening simultaneously.

So, the possible solution is making another super parent of the elements and taking the close button out of the element which is making it visible when clicked and adding a `ng-show` directive to the close button.

Checkout the following snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>

  <section class="page-section about-us" scroll-bookmark="about-us" ng-init="activeSection=false">
    <div ng-click="activeSection=true" class="page-content sub-content active-section">{{activeSection}}
      <div class="page-border">
        <a href="#" class="close-section"><img src="public/images/go-back-icon.png" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="activeSection" class="back-button" ng-click="activeSection=false">CLOSE</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I'm aware that the parent element may be interfering with interaction of the child element. And you are right: the ideal solution would be to separate these two buttons. But because of the way the app "morphs" from one state to the other using css animations, the easiest way for me to style this in css is by parenting the child button. Because the "back" button actually starts out as a background element in the "false" state.

Comment: Yeah, it is the only simplest solution.